# What should be the contents of the "describe your undergraduate program" while applying for grad schools?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, switzerland

I've come across a university where I'm required to give details about my undergraduate program (including course transcripts). Nothing else has been mentioned about this  submission. What should I include in this and how should I go about writing this part?

Answer (score 1):

My undergrad program was unique because I got field placements and collected original data. I presented in the student papers session at conference. We had a small campus and professors lived among us. We went to their houses for meals and knew their kids. In addition to being a top ranked, blah blah blah, we had this. Most undergrads are just taking classes and seeing TA's alot. My professors taught all classes and no TA's. No class was above 20 students in my major. No lecture hall except the 101 course, 60 students. What is unique and why is it better? My school had essay on every exam no matter the field. Multiple choice for quiz only. What beyond a textbook and the title of the course did you actually get for the money you paid for the class. Tell them that.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem that a section of this type is attempting to address is that there is a vast diversity of undergraduate educations out there, and the faculty evaluating your application may not be familiar with your particular university or program.  Even a transcript is not sufficient, as the "same" course at two different universities may have radically different content and level of educational quality.

Thus, faculty are likely to find value in knowing things like:

- What textbooks did you use?
- Was there lots of laboratory or project work, or was it all theory?
- How big did the classes tend to be, and how much interaction did you have with faculty?
- How well ranked is the university?
- Where do the students tend to come from, and where do they tend to go afterwards?